# "synonyms" and "word-choice" tags

Tags: discussion, tagging, tags

I think that "synonyms" and "word-choice" tags cover intersecting sets of questions.

The "synonyms" tag doesn't have a wiki, so there is hardly a chance to find out what the tag was intended for. It now covers 3 questions: "*народ* vs *люди*", "synonyms for *срач*" and "*мир* vs. *свет*".

The "word-choice" tag wiki tells that it is for questions about difference in usage and meaning.

Some other language sites also have both tags, but I cannot figure out what is the difference between them. Can someone explain me how these tags differ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [synonyms](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonyms) tag is used by questions that ask about related terms, but not only about "differences" between terms. For example:

> Is X a high registry synonym for Y?

This question would use this tag, but I don't think it would use the other one.

The [word-choice](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-choice) tag, instead, is specifically about a word choice in a certain sentence. But it's not necessarily about synonymous terms. It can be, but not always.

Comment: Ok, so what tag should questions like "What is the difference between these two synonymous words" use?

Comment: Both are ok! We don't need to choose absolutely just one. Ask yourself "What is this question about?" and you add the tags about that, even if they are related. Of course `synonyms` and `synonym` are not OK. We should choose one there.

Comment: We only have one, "synonyms". Thanks for the explanation, I'll write the tag wiki then.

Comment: @Olga Great! :)